# Any "Close Calls" on the Zeta function

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

As you all know, it is an open problem whether or not there exist zeroes within $0<x<1$ other than on the line $x=1/2$ (if $x$ is the real part). I was wondering what are some of the closest values to $0$ and at what point do they occur. I am only looking for local minima within $0<x<1$ (not points that approach an already known zero on the line $x=1/2$). Thanks.

Comment: $\zeta(z)$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{1\}$ so $|\zeta(z)|$ doesn't have any local minimum except where it is zero, see the [maximum modulus principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Zeta function universality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_function_universality).

Let $f$ be *any* everywhere nonzero analytic function on a closed and bounded subset $U$ of the $\mathrm{Re}(z) \in (1/2, 1)$ vertical strip.

Let $\epsilon$ be any positive real number.

Then there exists a nonnegative real constant $t$ such that

$$ | \zeta(z + \mathrm{i} t) - f(z) | < \epsilon $$

everywhere on the set $U$.

Thus, by changing $f$ and $U$, you can make $\zeta(z)$ take values arbitrarily close to zero at points arbitrarily close to the $\mathrm{Re}(z) = 1/2$ vertical line. I suppose the imaginary parts would tend to be rather large, though.

I suppose to satisfy your constraints, you might pick $(f,U)$ pairs such that $|f|$ takes large values on the part of the boundary near the $\mathrm{Re}(z) = 1/2$ line, and takes its minimum on the boundary on the opposite side.

Comment: What ? $\zeta(z)$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{1\}$ so $|\zeta(z)|$ doesn't have any local minimum except where it is zero

Comment: @user1952009: Okay, I've removed that comment. I suppose that explains why I wasn't able to imagine any nonzero functions that have large values on the boundary of a disk but a small value inside.

Comment: Also the universality on some strip is quite common for Dirichlet series with Euler product and analytic continuation, and for many other analytic functions